# Change font size of axis labels in pairs plots

Tags: r, plot, fonts

I am using `pairs` function to make scatter plots like the below plot. 
[image]

I wanna increase size of numbers in axis labels, but I do not know. I appreciate if anyone can help.

You can use the below instructions to generate sample plot:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(120*5),ncol=5)
col <- c("#3ABEB0", "#DD96A4")[c(rep(1, 60), rep(2,60))]
pairs(x, col = col, lower.panel = NULL, cex.labels=2, pch=19, cex = 0.8)
```

Comment: you can use parameter `cex.axis`. See `?par`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cex.axis`:

```
library(colorspace)
x <- matrix(rnorm(120*5),ncol=5)
col <- (rainbow_hcl(2))[c(rep(1, 60), rep(2,60))]
pairs(x, col = col, lower.panel = NULL, cex.labels=2, pch=19, cex = 0.8, cex.axis = 2)
```